# How to make html page as Home Page

Tags: magento-1.9

Our home page is constant, there is no changes in time.

I've generated exact .html copy of home page and it's served much faster.

How can i make magento use my home1.html page as home page?

Comment: you can put your html code into cms page and make it as home pageby `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General (Left) -> Web > Default Pages ->  CMS Home Page`

Comment: i already did, but still there is the difference. cms page is faster than let say product page, but pure html is much faster than cms page.

Comment: You can select layout 'empty'. Not 1column, 2columns-left,... so you get rid of header, footer and all unnecessary stuff that comes with Magento default template and you can add your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use/call your template inside your cms(home) page.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/your_path/home1.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

Comment: i need html, did you mean {{block type="core/template" template="theme/your_path/home1.html"  name="myname"}} ?

Comment: You can your html code inside phtml file.